# Can I get a text value between tags in React-Native markup

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to access a text value from inside a html tag from a child component in react native without using a prop? ...

```
render() {
 return (
  <View style={[styles.container]}>
    <BoxItem>Hello</BoxItem>
  </View>
 );
}
```

I would like to use the value "Hello" in the html markup in my BoxItem component? Here is the BoxItem component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './styles';

class BoxItem extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        id: PropTypes.string,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.itemStyles]}>
                <Text>{html_value}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default BoxItem;
```

How can I pass the variable that contains the value "Hello" instead of my placeholder `{html_value}`?

I could use a prop on the boxItem property, but I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) property.
You can access all the elements between  opening and closing tags of a component using `children` property.

In your case you can use

```
return (
            <View style={[styles.itemStyles]}>
                <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
            </View>
)
```

Hope it helps you.